# Where am I going wrong with this simple Python list problem?

Tags: python, list

The problem consists of a list of strings where each string has two elements and can be either a letter or a number, we want to create a function that takes this list as a parameter/argument and delete all those strings that have a number in it, I tried this code down below but it does not work.

```
def erase(lista):
    for word in lista:
        for letter in range (len(word)):
            if letter in [1234567890]:
                del word


erase(["a3", "b3", "aa"])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "it does not work" mean, specifically? Do you get error messages? What do they say? Does it just do something unexpected? What do you expect, and what happens instead? Please read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering that fast, actually it does not recognize whether each letter is in the number array or not so the word cant be erased, do you know how this problem could be solved?, Thanks!

Comment: That is because your line `if letter in [1234567890]:` is completely wrong. First of all the vaiable `letter` does not actually hold a letter - it is ints from the `range(len(word))`. You probably meant `for letter in word`. Second you are basically checking if that letter/number is equal to `1234567890`. Again, you probably meant `if letter.isdigit()`

Comment: fabr0, please add your specific question into the question, so as to make it on-topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if a char is a number, you can use `isdigit` function

```
my_list = ["a3", "b3", "aa"]

def erase(lista):
    only_chars = []
    for word in lista:
        result = ''.join([w for w in word if not w.isdigit()])
        if result:
            only_chars.append(result)

    return only_chars


result = erase(my_list)
print(result)
```

it will print:

```
['a', 'b', 'aa']
```

If you want to remove all string that contains numbers, you can use `isdigit` combined with `any`:

```
my_list = ["a3", "b3", "aa"]

def erase(lista):
    only_chars = []
    for word in lista:
        if not any(w.isdigit() for w in word):
            only_chars.append(word)

    return only_chars


result = erase(my_list)
print(result)
```

And now, the result is:

```
['aa']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but far from deleting the number element I need to remove all the string from the list, not only the element, am I clear?

Comment: You can check if there is a number in your string with any + isdigit. I added a example with any in my answer

Comment: Thanks you just solved my problem!!

Comment: Or simply put: `if word.isalpha()`

Comment: The problem with `isalpha` is that if the string contains for example `"a#@!"`, `isalpha()` will return `False`